# having troubles with fetching data from the database on livehost

Tags: mysql

i have created a database using phpmyadmin in the cpanel and imported the one i had created earlier from localhost to the livehost but there is no data showing on my website from the database.Even after changing,
localhost-to the new host,
root - to new username  and password.
Still nothing is showing on the website, what error could i have made?

Comment: 1) Is the data displayed properly on localhost? 2) Have your changed your dbconfig (or whatever you named your database configuration file, where you make your connection etc.) appropriately? 3) Are you using the corresponding PHP syntax according to the live host's version of PHP? Could you provide an example of your config file along with the info on your database name? Could you provide an example of where the page "breaks"?

Comment: yes on the localhost its working. i have changed the db file to the new details, i created in the cpanel( mysql) . <?php

$con= mysqli_connect("nothing.com","ndatabase","1234567","nothing_database");


if ($con->connect_error)
{
    echo $con->connect_error;
    die("sorry error");
}
 else
 {
   echo"";
 }
?>

Comment: You are providing *very* little information to your problem. Are you getting any error messages? Perhaps from sql? Or filestreem? (web servers are case sensitive). What happens if you `var_dump($your_sql_variable);` ? You need to give us *something* in order for us to help you...

Comment: Make sure that you localhost directory and web directory is *EXACTLY* the same. Make sure that you don't have any hardcoded "localhost" directories etc.

Comment: on the localhost, i am using localhost and on the live host i am using nothing.com but still not working, i tried to add a comment using echo, i am able to see the details but the data from the database nothing

Comment: var_dump($your_sql_variable); ? where should i try this?

Comment: I don't feel like you completely understood what I wrote so far. Please provide examples. Show us your dbconfig file. Show us 1 sample table along with a printed sql command. Please confirm the following steps: Localhost and online web host have the *EXACT* same directory structure and file contents. There are no failed filestreems, the webpage does not output *ANY* error messages regarding sql or filestreem. The console log does *NOT* show any errors. (ctrl+shift+i > console in Chrome to check console).

Comment: $res=mysqli_query($con,"select * FROM about");
         if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);   this is the code i am using to fetch data from the database

Comment: Answer to "var_dump($your_sql_variable); ? where should i try this?" Anywhere you make sql attemps. This is a php function. Try to echo it on any page, `$your_sql_variable` obviously being the php variable containing your sql command string.

Comment: Try to see my past comment and go through the steps. Localhost and online directory is the *EXACT* same, no differences in file structure or contents. There are no "failed to open filestream" error messages displayed on the website. There are no sql errors displayed on the website. The console log does not display any errors (ctrl+shift+i > console in Chrome). Please check all of this.

Comment: this is my dconfig file <?php

$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nothing_database");  this is a table in the database 
CREATE TABLE `about` (
  `about_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `about_title` text NOT NULL,
  `about_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `about_image` longblob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; to fetch data this $res=mysqli_query($con,"select * FROM about");
         if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);


if ($con->connect_error)
{
    echo $con->connect_error;
    die("sorry error");
}
 else
 {
   echo"";
 }
?>

Comment: Please integrate code and example in context with your question so that it is proper formated and easily found by new readers. And still refer to my previous comment(s).

Comment: var_dump($your_sql_variable); when i try this code in the php it shows nothing

Comment: Because you are not using a variable to contain your sql command, you are inserting the string directly into your `mysqli_query();` function. It won't work regardless if you 100% copy paste it either, `$your_sql_variable` legit is whatever you would choose to call the variable that would contain your sql string. I'm sorry, but you are missing a lot of basics that makes it hard to help you, you also *ignored* my step by step confirmation process to make it 100% clear on specifics that could help you advance in your problem.

Comment: Localhost and online have the exact same directory structure and contain the *EXACT* same files - can you confirm? Yes/no? Be 100% sure. Your webpage does *NOT* display *ANY* sql errors or filestream errors - can you confirm? Yes/no? Your browser console (ctrl+shift+i >console in Chrome) displays *NO* errors - can you confirm? Yes/no?

Comment: You also have not yet integrated *ANY* code in your originally posted question or anything at all that could be of significance in any way of being possibly able to help you... Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thank you Martin, the problem was solved. the host directory was the one giving an error, instead of " localhost:3306", i was just supposed to use "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

While the problem was solved through comments, I'd like to summarize the steps one should take when facing this issue.

1. Make sure that your localhost is using the correct directory.
2. Make sure that the directory structure is exactly the same on
   localhost/online.
3. Make sure that both directories contain the exact same files.
4. Web servers are case sensitive as opposed to localhost environments,
   make sure that you have no filestream errors or similar (i.e
   includes etc.).
5. Make sure that you have no SQL errors. It should display in the
   browser if you do.
6. Make sure you have no JavaScript errors (ctrl+shift+i in Chrome >
   console tab).
7. Try to do an uncashed refresh (ctrl+f5 in Chrome).